# Make taxable a WooCommerce custom fee based on payment gateway and country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, checkout

This code adds a fee of 29 when PayPal is selected on checkout page for a defined country. However, it's not being taxed. The total tax right now is based on items + shipping.

How would I go about to add tax to the custom fee without double taxing people?

This is my code:

```
function woocommerce_custom_fee( ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $county = array('SE');
    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || ! is_checkout() )
        return;

    $chosen_gateway = $woocommerce->session->chosen_payment_method ;

    $fee = 29;


    if ( $chosen_gateway == 'paypal' and ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) )  ) { //test with paypal method
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Paypal Avgift', $fee, false, '' );    
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_fee' );
function cart_update_script() {
    if (is_checkout()) :
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {

            // woocommerce_params is required to continue, ensure the object exists
            if ( typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined' ) {
                return false;
            }

            $checkout_form = $( 'form.checkout' );

            $checkout_form.on( 'change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function() {
                    $checkout_form.trigger( 'update' );
            });


        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_script', 999 );
```

Thanks

Comment: how do you intend computing tax? Do you have a ready formula?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I tried with `$total_taxes = array_sum($woocommerce->cart->get_taxes());` but it didn't help. I am not sure I am using it right. Took me all day just to get the main code working ( I started with PHP 3 weeks ago)

Comment: [$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_tax][https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#2189-2198] returns the total tax for all items in the cart. My question is, do you think tax isn't currently being applied to the cart?

Comment: @ErikaJohansson … No problem we have all pass through this once like you. In your future question don't forget to mention that you are using Klarna plugin and give a max of details about…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To enable Tax in [**`WC_Cart add_fee()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee) method, you need to set the third argument to **`true`**. 
>   You can remove the last argument as it is already the default value.

In **`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`** action hook you can use directly the cart object argument **`$cart_obj`** that is include in it.

Also **`global $woocommerce`** has been replaced by **`WC()`** object which include it (so no need anymore to declare **`global $woocommerce`**.

Below I have clean and reordered your first hooked function, try it *(it will act as yours, and fee will be taxable)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','conditional_payment_mothod_custom_fee', 10, 1 );
function conditional_payment_mothod_custom_fee( $cart_obj ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! is_checkout() )
        return;

    $fee = 19;
    $target_county = 'SE';
    $chosen_gateway = WC()->session->chosen_payment_method;
    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();

    // Enabling fee with paypal method (and 'SE' country)
    if('paypal' == $chosen_gateway && $shipping_country == $target_county)
        $cart_obj->add_fee( __('Paypal Avgift'), $fee, true ); // Tax enabled for the fee
}
```

> Here **`$cart_obj`** act just as **`$woocommerce->cart`** or **`WC()->cart`**

Now in your second function, you can use the jQuery shortcut [**`change()`**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) and you can make your code more modern and compact, this way:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_update_script', 999 );
function checkout_update_script() {
    if ( is_checkout() ) :
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( function($){
            // Checking that the variable "woocommerce_params" is defined to continue               
            if ( 'undefined' === typeof woocommerce_params )
                return false;

            $('form.checkout').change('input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
                $(this).trigger( 'update' );
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works on WooCommerce versions 2.6.x and 3.0+

Comment: This code still works on WooCommerce versions 5.4.x